# Get FLOAT texture from C++ AMP instead of TYPELESS

Tags: uwp, directx-11, c++-amp

I want to display an image produced with C++ AMP in an UWP application in the most efficient way possible.

My approach is to move the C++ AMP data into an ID3D11Texture2D that can be displayed in UWP.
To do this I'm copying the data to a texture created with:

```
unsigned int bitsPerScalarElement = 32;
auto ampTexture = Concurrency::graphics::texture<Concurrency::graphics::float_4, 2>(m_width, m_height, bitsPerScalarElement);
```

This however results in a texture with the DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_TYPELESS texture format.
I would like this to be DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, otherwise UWP will not be able to display it. It complains that "The bitmap pixel format is unsupported".

According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2012/07/02/interop-with-direct3d11-textures-in-c-amp/ I should only have to set the bitsPerScalarElement when creating the texture to choose the type, but it is not working for me.

Anyone who can help me here?

Below is a test program to verify the format returned:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <amp.h>
#include <amp_graphics.h>

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <wrl.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int bitsPerScalarElement = 32;
    auto ampTexture = Concurrency::graphics::texture<Concurrency::graphics::float_4, 2>(500, 500, bitsPerScalarElement);

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> d3dTexture;
    auto hr = Concurrency::graphics::direct3d::get_texture(ampTexture)->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&d3dTexture);
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    d3dTexture->GetDesc(&texDesc);

    std::cout << "Format: " << texDesc.Format << "\n";
}
```

For me this returns 1, which maps to DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_TYPELESS according to dxgiformat.h. I'm running on GeForce GTX 1070 driver 416.34.

Comment: Do you mean when you use `Concurrency::graphics::texture` to create texture, it returns DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_TYPELESS format? When I tested it, I didn't find it returned DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_TYPELESS format, can you show more details about the result and how to identify if it is a TYPELESS format? In addition, When I followed the link to create a direct3d device to create a texture, it could create a DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT format of texture, have you tried this? Did it work for you? Did you only want to use `Concurrency::graphics::texture` method to create a texture?

Comment: I have updated my question with a full test program for the texture format. You also need to turn off Conformance mode with "no" instead of "/permissive-" in VS2017, otherwise the included amp_graphics.h won't compile (error C3861: '_Texture_base': identifier not found).